# App returns from the background - change frame.origin of bar

Tags: ios, xcode, background

I have a navigation bar that change it position when the table scroll up. It works fine **but when my app enter background and next return - navigation bar is on  its basic place, not the place it was before entering background**.I used notification center to change it place like this

```
    var navBarOldFrame : CGPoint!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "becameActive", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "enterForeground", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "inactiveState", name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
     super.viewDidLoad()
     }

    func inactiveState(){
    print("inactive:")
    println(navBar.frame.origin.y)
    navBarOldFrame = navBar.frame.origin
}

 func enterForeground(){
    print("active:")
    println(navBar.frame.origin.y)
navBar.frame.origin = navBarOldFrame
}
func becameActive(){
    print("active:")
    println(navBar.frame.origin.y)
navBar.frame.origin = navBarOldFrame
}
```

And in selectors i change origin, but it still on the basic place, and I need to put it to the old place! How can i do it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please do post an answer if you have found the issue. PS: I am using objectiveC